# Commerce one-step checkout

Tags: commerce

ok heres the thing.

Im working on a one-step checkout with drupal commerce, but keep encountering issues xD

the setup has 2 shipping methods, one is a flatrate and second is "pickup at store".

When the user selects "Pickup at store", he needs to press a link to open a Ctools modal, presenting a list of available stores, wich also are presented on a googlemap in this modal dialog.

My issue now is to return the selected store from the Ctool modal, back to the checkoutpage.

Currently what i do is setting the selected location in the cart_orders data array, saves the order and replace some HTML with the address of the selected location.

After doing this, i have to submit the checkout form twice, to complete the order?
First submit does aparently nothing (i suspect it somehow updates the order??) and second submit completes the checkout.

Questions are
   1) Are there any better way to append the selected location to the order??
   2) By any chance any of you have experienced the "double submit" for completing the checkout?